# I built the OpenCV so file to be used in Unity Android successfully, but why can't my app find the Dll?

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity-game-engine, opencv

I want to use **opencv-4.8.0-android** sdk to write the desired source and then call it from Unity Android. My environment is as follows.

- Visual studio 2022, running on win10
- *android-ndk-r23c* and also tried with *r21d* that is same with unity editor ndk
- Unity 2021.3.22, arm64 (Test device is Galaxy S21 +)
- Visual studio properties

  - General

    - Platform toolset : Clang 5.0
    - Configuration type : *.so
    - Target API level : android-21 (same to unity api level)
    - Use STL : LLVM libc++ c++_static (also tried shared)
  - C/C++

    - Additional include directories : opencv-4.8.0-android\sdk\native\jni\include
    - Language : c++17(-std=c++1z)
  - Linker

    - General, Additional library directories : opencv-4.8.0-android\sdk\native\libs\arm64-v8a
    - Input, Additional dependencies : opencv-4.8.0-android\sdk\native\libs\arm64-v8a\libopencv_java4.so

I wrote the code below and successfully built the so file.

```cpp
#include "OpenCVwithUnityAndroid.h"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TestSharedObject", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "TestSharedObject", __VA_ARGS__))

extern "C" {
    const char* OpenCVwithUnityAndroid::getPlatformABI()
    {
#if defined(__arm__)
    #if defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__)
        #if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
            #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON"
        #else
            #define ABI "armeabi-v7a"
        #endif
    #else
        #define ABI "armeabi"
    #endif
#elif defined(__i386__)
    #define ABI "x86"
#else
    #define ABI "unknown"
#endif
        return "This native library is compiled with ABI: %s" ABI ".";
    }

    struct Color32
    {
        uchar red;
        uchar green;
        uchar blue;
        uchar alpha;
    };

    void OpenCVwithUnityAndroid::FlipImage(Color32** rawImage1, int width1, int height1) {
        using namespace cv;
        Mat Image(height1, width1, CV_8UC4, *rawImage1);
        flip(Image, Image, -1);
    }
}
```

The built *libOpenCVwithUnityAndroid.so* file was moved to Unity's plugins/android directory.
The target architecture is ARM64, and the APK was built with IL2CPP.
However, when I run it in my test environment, I get a **DllNotFoundException**.

In the same environment, after creating a so file without importing OpenCV, I was able to check the log without any problem when calling *getPlatformABI()*.

Before going through all of this, I created a DLL in a Windows environment and confirmed that the image was flipped when I called the *FilpImage()* function in Unity. However, I don't know what the problem is in the Android environment.